# Don't store documents with duplicated key in Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I want to avoid duplicated keys in different documents.

For example, in the document 1 I have this:

```
{
  "user": "myuser",
  "email: "a@a.com"
}
```

In the document 2 I have:

```
{
  "user": "myuser2",
  "email: "b@b.com"
}
```

And in document 3 I have:

```
{
  "user": "myuser",
  "email: "c@c.com"
}
```

I don't want to be possible to create document 3, as the user key has the same value. Is possible to do this with database rules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add the document with `user` as a unique ID like that

```
db.collection("Your Collection").document(user).set(Your Object)
```

"user" is the user field of your object

Answer (score -1):

one solution could be using `email` address as an unique `id` for your document, because email addresses are always **unique**:

`db.collection("collection/" + userObject.email).set(userObject)`

or

`db.collection("collection").doc(email).set(user object)`

Comment: The question is asking how to make it impossible to create duplicates in the "user" column, so that would be a better choice for the id in this case.